# MVC5 display message on client before app publish

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, signalr

Is it possible to display any message for all users before publishing application automatically?

I would like to display some message popup that there will be an update on server and user can be prompted to logIn again.
As a temporary solution, I think to use signalr to broadcast this message to all users.

Is there any out of the box functionality for this action?

Comment: I think SignalR will be the best choice for such functionality

Comment: I think SignalR is best too. But if you don't want to use SignalR, You can create a Notification table at db, and at browser use polling to get the Notification data

Answer (score 0):

SignalR is the best choice for real time communication with the client from an ASP.net website. In your case, you may use SignalR JavaScript client and SignalR hubs to notify all the online users about the server update. Or you may even log the user out remotely if you are using [JS accessible] cookies to store the authentication ticket at the client side.